# Responsive Design Issue With Real Mobile Devices

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, responsive

I have recently created an html page and made it responsive successfully in accordance with Browsers Dev Tools.

I have also added `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in html page.

In (mobile browser's dev tools of mozilla and chrome) everything is fine; however, when I check it in actual mobile device some css items are not working correctly and not showing propely! They render outside of its container!

Here is Responsive CSS code:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .side-title{
font-size: 0.5rem;


    }

}


@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    
.side-content{
left:0;
right:0;

margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;

bottom: 0%;
width:300px;
height: 30px;
}


.side-btn-link{
    top:0px;
}


.swip-helper-container{
    top:70%;
    font-size:8rem;
    
        }

.side-icon{
height: 30px;
width: 30px;
font-size:1.5rem;
}


.side-btn-link:hover .side-icon {
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color:transparent;
color:#aaaaaa;

}


.bottom-content{

    display: none;
}


    .building-title{
font-size:1.25rem;

    }
    .constructor-title{
        font-size:0.5rem;

    }
  
    .top-content{
        top:0;
    }

}


@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    .swip-helper-container{
top:65%;
font-size:5rem;

    }


.side-title{
display: none;

}


    .building-title{
        font-size:1.05rem;
        
            }
            .constructor-title{
                font-size:0.7rem;
        
            }


    
    .top-content{

top:0;
width:100%;
right:0;
height: 35px;

    }

.seller-logo-link{

display: block;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
border-top:none;
height: auto;
}


.seller-logo{
display: none;
float: none;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 50%;


}
.title-container{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}


.building-title{

width:100%;
text-align: center;
height:100%;
margin: 0;
line-height: 2;

}


.constructor-title{
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;

}

    }
```

Could someone help to solve this issue?

Comment: Share some code. Besides, what do you exaclty mean by added "" in html page

Comment: meta tag had been missed! I added so.

Comment: Still to wide. Share at least a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You could perform a fast test with `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">`, see if you have better results.

Comment: I have implemented meta tag you rectified. The problem still exist:(